# How mysql repeatable read prevent phantom read

Tags: mysql, database, transactions, locking, isolation-level

According to this [blog](https://blog.pythian.com/understanding-mysql-isolation-levels-repeatable-read/).

I also try this by myself. I saw that phantom read does not happen in repeatable read.
I wonder how MySQL implements this underlying to preserve the snapshot of the range query.

Table: `test`

| ID | num |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |

| Tx1 | Tx2 |
| --- | --- |
| START TRANSACTION | START TRANSACTION |
| SELECT * FROM `test`; # Return 1 | SELECT * FROM `test`; # Return 1 |
| INSERT INTO `test` VALUES(2,2); # OK | SELECT * FROM `test`; # Return 1 |
| COMMIT |  |
|  | SELECT * FROM `test`; # Still return 1, phantom rows not appeared |

Comment: Just because a phantom read _might_ occur does not necessarily mean that it _will_ occur.  It could be that your two transactions happen to not be overlapping, due to the way your test be setup.

Comment: Could you help to show me an example of phantom read in MySQL(not phantom write)?

Comment: Perhaps https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-multi-versioning.html will help understand. Serializability is a side-effect of the multi-versioning of INNODB.